# Convert object values to array of objects

Tags: javascript

How to change the generated numbered object keys to a different name for all keys to be the same?

```
const obj = { 0: "81", 1: "82", 2: "83" }
```

I need to make it

```
Object { name: "81"}, 
Object { name: "82"},
Object { name: "83" }
```

Comment: An object can have a given property name only once. You could make it an array of *separate* objects.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @Pointy, you are right. I edited the question. I need to make multiple objects from the array.

Comment: @j08691, I already have the object created. I don't think you need to see code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply map through the values of the object with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const obj = { 0: "81", 1: "82", 2: "83" }
const newArr = Object.values(obj).map(e => ({name: e}))
console.log(newArr);
```